# Custom Listview Scrolling is Very Slow,how to make listview scrolling smooth?

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I have a **"XYZ Class"** which extends **view**. In this class i am creating circles view through java code. and is class i am calling in listView's custom adapter class in getView() method.So when i am displaying  "XYZ Class" view in list view. my scrolling is very slow. if i removed this class ,then scrolling is fast or normal in listview. i also used asynctask in getview method while calling this "XYZ class". So why my listview scrolling is slow ,when i called view class in listview adapter.

Please help me.how i'll call "XYZ view Class" in getview()?

Comment: add in to Listview xml <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_files"
    ...
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
</ListView>

Comment: I already did that but it is not working